# Google analytics organic search loop problems

Tags: loops, google-analytics

The loop functions completely different and I'm not sure if it is because of the google analytics package because very little is different between the code.

Doesn't WORK  difference in print statement output shows results are not coming out correctly.

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)
library(tidyverse)

#settings
start_dat <- as.character(Sys.Date()-31)
end_dat <- as.character(Sys.Date()-1)


#Authorize Google Analytics R- this will open a webpage
#You must be logged into your Google Analytics account on your web browser
ga_auth()

account_sum <- ga_account_list()



#Add the start and end date to the date frame, as well as some columns to use to populate the metrics
account_sum$start_dat <- start_dat
account_sum$end_dat <- end_dat

## choose the v3 segment
segment_for_call <- "gaid::-5"

## make the v3 segment object in the v4 segment object:
seg_ob <- segment_ga4("OrganicTraffic", segment_id = segment_for_call)


# cycle through the list of views, pull the data, and add it to the
#account_summary

for (i in 1:5){

  view_id <- (Book1CSV[[1]][i])
  views=view_id




  ga_dat <- google_analytics_4(views, 
                            date_range = c(start_dat, end_dat),
                            segments = seg_ob,
                            metrics = c("sessions", "pageviews"),
                            dimensions = c("year","segment"))

  ga_dat <- summarise(ga_dat,
                       sessions = sum(sessions),
                       pageviews = sum(pageviews))

  account_sum$sessions[i] <- ga_data$sessions
  account_sum$pageviews[i] <- ga_data$pageviews
  print(account_summary)
}

clean_sum <- select(account_sum,
                        ID = webPropertyId ,
                        Account = accountName,
                        Views = views,
                        Type = type,
                        Level = level,
                        'Start Date' = start_dat,
                        'End Date' = end_dat,
                        Sessions = sessions,
                        Pageviews = pageviews)



write.csv (ga_dat, "doesntwork.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```

THIS WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Print statement prints code

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)
library(tidyverse)

#settings
start_date <- as.character(Sys.Date()-31)
end_date <- as.character(Sys.Date()-1)
metrics <- c("sessions", "pageviews")
dimensions <- "year"

#Authorize Google Analytics R- this will open a webpage
#You must be logged into your Google Analytics account on your web browser
ga_auth()

account_summary <- ga_account_list()



#Add the start and end date to the date frame, as well as some columns to use to populate the metrics
account_summary$start_date <- start_date
account_summary$end_date <- end_date


# cycle through the list of views, pull the data, and add it to the
#account_summary

for (i in 1:6){

  view_id <- (Book1CSV[[1]][i])

  ga_data <- google_analytics_4(viewId = view_id,
                                date_range = c(start_date,end_date),
                                metrics = metrics,
                                dimensions = dimensions)

  # This query might return multiple rows (if it spans a year boundary), so
  #collapse and clean up

  ga_data <- summarise(ga_data,
                       sessions = sum(sessions),
                       pageviews = sum(pageviews))

  #add the totals to the account summary

  account_summary$sessions[i] <- ga_data$sessions
  account_summary$pageviews[i] <- ga_data$pageviews
  print(account_summary)
}

# Make a more compact set of data

clean_summary <- select(account_summary,
                        Account = accountName,
                        View = viewId,
                        Type = type,
                        Level = level,
                        'Start Date' = start_date,
                        'End Date' = end_date,
                        Sessions = sessions,
                        Pageviews = pageviews,
                        ID = webPropertyId)
select

write.csv (clean_summary, "worksfine.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Can't really understand whats going wrong here. Would like some detailed help. I have uploaded a file called `Book1CSV` as I couldn't get a try-catch statement that would work to catch the error. Google merchant store beta account was causing the crash.

Comment: So does "Google merchant store beta account was causing the crash." mean the issue is resolved?

Comment: Still causing the crash just downloaded all of the accounts and removed the beta account and uploaded them into a list in Book1CSV. Couldnt get a try catch statement to work. The issue now is pulling multiple organic searches. When it runs theres something wrong with the print in the loop. Working fine for bottom code but not for top even through their printing the same :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an anti-R pattern, modifying an object in a loop.  Its better to return a list of data.frames, then merge then at the end and create your summary.

So something like:

```
my_view_ids <- c(12345,233445,232434)

## fetch data, create a list of 
all_data <- lapply(my_view_ids, function(id){
  one_data <- tryCatch(google_analytics_4(viewId = id,
                 date_range = c(start_date,end_date),
                 metrics = metrics,
                 dimensions = dimensions),
               error = function(ex){message(ex); NULL})
  one_data$viewId <- id
  one_data
})

## Reduce the list of data.frames to one data.frame
all_dataframe <- Reduce(rbind, all_data)

### make your summary etc.
```

Comment: It now works exactly how I want it too!! Wish I could upvote your comment but not ranked high enough haha. Have not coded in R before so really handy to know that for loops don't work when modifying the object. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hey can you take a look at my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404867/calling-ga-goal-from-the-googleanalyticsr-package