# calling ga_goal from the googleanalyticsr package

Tags: google-analytics-api

Hi I am trying to call find goals but cant get the right style I am currently being returned 
Error: API returned: invalid webPropertyId: 79885916.

Im sure that this isn't wrong as my analytics url contains a48372046w79885916p82626620/

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)
library(ggplot2)

ga_auth()

my_accounts <- ga_account_list()

account <- ga_goal(48372046, 79885916, 82626620, 4)

write.csv (account, "r.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may need the web property UA code, which is in the form `UA-33333-1` that you can find in the `ga_account_list()` results.

An example would be

`ga_goal(48372046, "UA-1223455", 82626620, 4)`

Comment: Putting the UA code allowed me to accept the connection of the API but did not solve the problem. 
Error in ga_account_list(UA - 48372046 - 1) : 
  unused argument (UA - 48372046 - 1)

Request failed [400]. Retrying in 1 seconds...
2017-11-24 09:13:50> Request Status Code: 400


Error: API returned: invalid webPropertyId: 79885916.

Comment: The error suggests you didn't use the web property UA code, like this: `ga_goal(48372046, "UA-1223455", 82626620, 4)`